# Velocity Macro Line Break

Tags: apache, jira, velocity, jira-plugin

Given the following macro:

```
#macro(sample $c1 $c2 $c3 $c4)
    ## do something with $c1..4
#end
```

My problem is that the input of #sample is very long, and everything would be more readable if I were to call it in the following manner

```
#sample(  $c1
          $c2
          $c3
          $c4 )
```

But this only grants a whitespace-error. Given that the only reason for me to use this macro is readability, I would like to make this somehow work. Any ideas?

Cheers!

Comment: For those who happened to stumble upon this post: After some long googling sessions, and a lot of try-and-fail, it would seem that there is no obvious solution to this. The closes answer I'v'e found is the one provided by Seika85 below, yet for my situation I feel it is too complicated.

If your situation requires a lot of arguments, then maybe Seika's suggestion is the best alternative, but for few inputs, like mine, finding a way to alter the input data to a shorter format would probably be a better alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to do something like this:

```
#set( $options = [ "one",
                   "two",
                   "three",
                   "four" ] )
#macro(sample $options)
   #foreach( $opt in $options )
       ## do something with each $opt
   #end
#end
```

Another thing is trying to use comments (if I remember correctly). Maybe something like that:

```
#sample(  $c1 #*
       *# $c2 #*
       *# $c3 #*
       *# $c4 )
```

As I recall linebreaks where always buggy and wrapping them in comments would resolve those issues.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I tried the comment thing, but it did not work, still claiming whitespace error. One good solution would be to use arrays, yet this is more complicated than I'd like.
Recall that my motivation is to keep things simple and easy to read.